# Should I ignore \bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\ directory inside asp.net core app?

Tags: git, asp.net-core

Creating asp.net core application, should I add \bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\ directory inside .gitignore file?
I tried to find any answer on this question but no luck.
Is the any .gitignore example file for .xproj projects witch opens inside Visual Studio? I didn't find any example witch add *.xproj.user file for example. But I'm absolutely sure this file should be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The [Visual Studio `.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) from GitHub is often the best choice when developing .NET applications.

This includes ignoring the `[Bb]in/` directory, in addition to `*.user` pattern which will ignore `*.xproj.user`.